WCF service not getting called
I am having wcf service which is running on dotnet framework 4.8.
This service is called from dotnet 7 application.
Now, we had a requirement where we need to use SAML based authentication. And for that we were using https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2 nuget package.
If we use version 4.0.8 of ITfoxtec, wcf service works but then saml authentication does not work because ITfoxtec does not support dotnet 7 for version 4.0.8.
If I upgrade to supported dotnet version which is 4.10.8, then okta saml works but then, wcf service does not work.
It gives this error (The CustomBinding on the ServiceEndpoint with contract 'Service1' lacks a TransportBindingElement.  Every binding must have at least one binding element that derives from TransportBindingElement)
Note: Application project reference is added in Web.Core project.
I can't upgrade wcf service to latest dotnet version. How can I support okta and wcf both?
This is how the project structure.


Have you upgraded System.Servicemodel to the latest? Alternatively, you can try to migrate and upgrade the old WCF service to Corewcf.

The only solution I can come op with is to divide the web application using SAML 2.0 and the API/WCF service into two separate applications.
